# When joining or merging data frames, what's the best way to deal with a field that has "no value" to indicate that all values are possible?

Tags: r, join, data.table, rbind

This provides an example of the situation.  Is there a way to handle this in R to get the desired outcome of main_df_2.  Or alternatively, is there a way that I could add rows to lookup_df such that the missing possibilities where (division ='d2') has (parent = 'P') and (parent ='C')  added as two rows in addition to the one blank row?

```
# example for the type of join 
library(tidyverse)
main_df <- data.frame( division = c('d1', 'd1', 'd2', 'd2'),
                       parent = c('P', 'C', 'P', 'C'))
main_df
# > main_df
# division parent 
# 1       d1      P
# 2       d1      C       
# 3       d2      P
# 4       d2      C
lookup_df <- data.frame( division = c('d1', 'd1', 'd2'),
                  parent = c('P', 'C', ''),
                  plant = c('A', 'B', 'B'))
lookup_df
# > lookup_df
# division parent plant
# 1       d1      P     A
# 2       d1      C     B
# 3       d2            B

# desired outcome 
# > main_df_2
# division parent plant
#    d1      P      A
#    d1      C      B
#    d2      P      B
#    d2      C      B

main_df_2 <- left_join(main_df, lookup_df,
                by = c("division" = "division",
                       "parent" = "parent"))

main_df_2
# > x1
# division parent plant
# 1       d1      P     A
# 2       d1      C     B
# 3       d2         <NA>
# 4       d2      C  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 options using `data.table`

1) Split into 2 separate join before row binding them:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(main_df)
setDT(lookup_df)

rbindlist(list(
    main_df[lookup_df, on=.(division, parent), nomatch=0L],
    main_df[lookup_df[parent==""], on=.(division), nomatch=0L, 
        .(division=x.division, parent=x.parent, plant=i.plant)]))
```

2) using a full out merge before filtering (more memory intensive if dataset is huge after join):

```
setnames(
    merge(lookup_df, main_df, by="division", all=TRUE)[
        parent.x==parent.y | parent.x==""][, 
            parent.x := NULL],
    "parent.y", "parent")
```

output:

```
   division parent plant
1:       d1      P     A
2:       d1      C     B
3:       d2      P     B
4:       d2      C     B
```

Comment: Thank you @chinsoon12 !  The 1st suggestion works and the actual data I am working with is indeed larger, half a million records with more columns.  I will read up on the data.table library more so I can use that for other applications in the future too.